# How to do Transient analysis?

Tags: circuit-analysis, differential, passive-networks, transient, laplace-transform

Consider the above example earlier I used to form a differential equation and then do its solution using Laplace,but for this example the differential equation comes out to be non-ordinary.

Please help to find *I(t)* consider initial rest.
[image]

My approach

[image]

Comment: show your calculation so far.